# How can n-gons be selected?

Tags: modeling, mesh, selection-tools, bmesh

Editing a mesh for a while I didn't notice that I created a n-gon. After adding a subsurf modifier the mesh heavily deformed, it took while until I found this:

[image]

Is there an easy way to select n-gons?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**Yes**.

Press *3D view > HEader > Select > Faces by Sides*:

[image]

Then set the *type* to *greater than* and the number of vertices to 4 in the *redo panel* (<kbd>F6</kbd> or at the bottom of the *tool shelf*):

[image]

**Edit Blender 2.8**

This option is now in Select > Select All by Trait > Faces by Sides
[image: Select faces by side blender 2.8]

Comment: You have to deselect your model using "a" before you do that when you model is currently entirely selected, else the N-gons will not be visible because the model is already entirely selected.