# Where is the cleanup menu in 2.74?

Tags: interface

I can't find any sort of mesh clean-up menu. I'd like to be able to find Ngons/degenerated faces/ect. quickly on large, complex meshes. Maya is great for this (highlights their locations without auto-fixing them). Can Blender do this?

I've checked the manual. It says to go to Mesh >> Cleanup. Where is this exactly?

Comment: Switch to edit mode and you will see the Mesh menu on the bottom of your 3D view window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a nice little addon called MeshLint for locating Tris, Ngons, Interior Faces etc. within my models. http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Modeling/MeshLint

Comment: That's perfect! Exactly what I was hoping for :D Thank you

Comment: As I read before it is a spell checker for a Mesh.

Comment: Could you add a little detail on how the addon works, to improve the answer?

Answer (score 10):

First, you need to be in *Edit* mode, then check the *3d view* header (the bar at the bottom) of the 3d view and you will see the *Mesh* menu item.

[image]

Additionally, you can press <kbd>Space</kbd> and search for the operation you want to perform if you know the name.

[image]

You can use Select Faces by Sides<sup>[[citation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18568/how-can-n-gons-be-selected)]</sup> to select all the n-gons like maya

Comment: That's great, thank you :) What about Ngons? Can Blender find these?

Comment: This did not answer the question.

Comment: @M.Miles Actually, your answer doesn't answer the question and should possibly be a comment on mine. What you answered was a followup, what op wants doesn't correlate with what he asked, if someone comes in the future looking for the mesh cleanup menu, they have it.