# Blender to Poser 10 issue

Tags: mesh, objects, export

I am having an issue where I am trying to transfer my weapon from blender to Poser 10 and I get weird shapes in poser that don't match the figure in Blender.

Blender with weapon:[image: My Weapon in Blender]

Then I make it an object using wavefront.

Poser 10 with the weapon imported from Blender, as you can see it does not match the blender image. [image]

Why is Poser 10 doing that?

Comment: I'm not an expert in exporting but the first thing I would check is look for [n-gons](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/36434/5705).  You can check for them using [this method](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/18569/5705).

Comment: Weldome to the site, @Animator3d. It would be helpful in answering your question if you would upload a copy of your blend file to [Blend-exhange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) or a similar site, and edit your question so it includes a link to the uploaded ~.blend file. If the error is not in the ~.blend file (and it might not be), then the question is out of he scope of the site because it is either about issues in the wavefornt file, or the Poser 10 software.

Answer (score 1):

When exporting hard surface models from Blender to other formats it's almost always the case that you get "weird" shading or even distortions due to smoothing.

One method to prevent that is using "Auto-Smooth Normals" in the Object Data panel.

The two pictures show the same model in Blender and in FBX Review, the first one without "Auto-Smooth Normals", the second one got exported with this option activated.

[image: export without auto-smooth normals]

[image]

You can read more about Smoothing [in the Blender Maual](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/smoothing.html#auto-smooth).

Comment: Something wrong with the link, but https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/smoothing.html seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Poser always trys to smooth any model you import.

In Poser select the object and look at the properties panel.
Make sure to uncheck smooth vertices.

You can also uncheck smooth vertices in the global preferences but it's always best to do it on a model by model basis using the properties panel.